# Configure Jasig CAS deployerContextConfig using cas.properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cas, spring-3, jasig

I'm working on an implementation of [Jasig CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) version [3.5.2.1](http://www.jasig.org/cas_server_3_5_2_1_release)

CAS 3.5.2.1 is a [Spring 3.1 MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html) application.

Currently, the app uses a [ContextLoaderListener](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) to populate the [WebApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) from an xml file called [deployerContextConfig.xml](https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/a56ec9aa133e5532d441726b186ee63f0a831fbf/cas-server-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml)

Can I use properties (such as those loaded from [cas.properties](https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/a56ec9aa133e5532d441726b186ee63f0a831fbf/cas-server-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/cas.properties)) within the deployerContextConfig.xml file? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on CAS 3.5.0 but I think it would be the same as your version.
First the web.xml will load all the *.xml file inside /WEB-INF/spring-configuration directory and /WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring-configuration/*.xml
      /WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

The /WEB-INF/spring-configuration/propertyFileConfigurer.xml will load the cas.properties file

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/cas.properties" />
```

Inside the deployerConfigContext.xml:

```
<!-- Define the contextSource -->
<bean id="contextSourceRepository" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
       <property name="pooled" value="false" />
       <property name="urls">
           <bean class="org.springframework.util.StringUtils"
                    factory-method="commaDelimitedListToSet">
                    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"
                           value="${ldap.repository.server.urls}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.authentication.manager.userdn}" />
        <property name="password" value="${ldap.authentication.manager.password}" />

        <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
             <map>
                 <entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout" value="${ldap.authentication.jndi.connect.timeout}" />
                 <entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout" value="${ldap.authentication.jndi.read.timeout}" />
                 <entry key="java.naming.security.authentication" value="${ldap.authentication.jndi.security.level}" />
             </map>
        </property>
</bean>
```

And your cas.properties:

```
ldap.repository.server.urls=ldap://ldap.usfca.edu:389
```